# Is it possible to migrate certain folders within project from TFS 2013 on-premise to online using OpsHub

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, opshub

In our current setup, we have a top level TFS project and all the projects within in as separate folders with their Dev and Main branch.

To start trying VS Team Services, I am looking into migrating just a folder(Project) from TFS 2013 on-premise project to Team Services. Can I do that?

The options I am getting are to choose the project collection but not the folders within it? Is there a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. You need to migrate everything as is.

If you want that level of control you need to use the TFS Integration Tools. They are a lot more configurable, and complicated to boot.

I would recommend that you move with only the head/tip.